# What is this single seat aerobatic plane?

Tags: aircraft-identification, single-engine

We saw this plane this week in NW Arkansas, curious what it is?  [image: photo of an unknown single seat aircraft at very low altitude]

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE!

Comment: If you snapped any more photos of it, please add them to the question.  Especially from different angles or showing more detail.

Comment: Please describe its maneuvers.  Why have you called it aerobatic?

Comment: Another 20 feet lower, and I would call it kindling.

Comment: Btw looks like I made an action re a proposed edit that I was being prompted to review, essentially simultaneously as someone else accepted the proposed edit.  Not trying to play round-and-round games here intentionally-- ; )

Comment: Do you have a really good zoom lens, or was this thing flying far closer to you than it should've been?  Normally you don't see planes flying this close to each other unless they're military or doing some kind of air-show, i.e., they're flying together deliberately and communicating with each other.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman -- what makes you think two planes were involved?

Comment: @quietflyer We have a photograph of a plane, from above, seems self-explanatory.  Unless the photographer was on a tall mountain maybe?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - I would think a point on an adjacent ridge, somewhat lower than elevation of ridge behind airplane (since far horizon cannot be seen beyond ridge behind airplane), but above actual elevation or altitude of target airplane, would be the perfect vantage point for this photo-- i.e. the airplane appears to be  flying down a valley slightly below the photographer's eye level, while banking toward the photographer --

Comment: Note that all the trees are equally in focus.  Suggesting a photo w/ a telephoto lens. No reason to assume that this plane was within inches or feet  of dragging its landing gear through any particular tree tops.

Comment: @quietflyer Yes, perspective and lens choice makes reality very hard to discern from that angle.  When I saw the photo, I just immediately imagined one of those infamous *"quick jumping trees"* taking that cute little bird down.

Answer (score 19):

It's a [GB-1 Game Bird](https://gamecomposites.com/gb1/) built by Game Composites.

[image]

This picture shows the two place configuration but the OP's photo shows the single place option which is why the nose looks longer.

Here is a single-place version:

[image]

It is indeed an unlimited class aerobatic aircraft.

Comment: The canopy looks rather different - barely reaches the trailing edge of the wing in the OP's photo.

Comment: @MikeB I'm not sure where you're looking, but the canopy extends pretty far into the wing in the OP's photo. The [single place GB-1](http://www.aero-news.net/index.cfm?do=main.textpost&id=e136e92b-0954-42af-af21-2580e070896e) looks the same.

Comment: The specs at the Game BIrd page says it has a total fuel capacity of 81gallons.  Not knowing anything about small planes - how far does that get you? (Doesn't _sound_ like much.) 'Cause that page also says the plane is "the best _touring_ airplane in the world".

Comment: @davidbak Around 1000 nautical miles, according to the link at the top of the answer.

Comment: @davidbak And with a cruise speed of 200kn, that equates to 4 minutes per gallon, sounds reasonable.

Comment: @MikeB -- note the completely different perspective (viewing angle) in the two photos of the single-seaters.  The aircraft geometry looks the same to me.  Just as a (swept-wing) aircraft with dihedral will appear to have anhedral when viewed  from certain angles, and vice versa--